# ¿Cómo añado una clase al elemento label en un formulario generado por Symfony?

Tags: formularios, symfony3

Tengo un `FormBuilder` de **Symfony3** y necesito que me añada una `class` al `label` de **descuentos**.
Cómo podeis observar el tercer parmetro del método `add` es un `array`´y una clave es `attr` la cual tiene otro array con los atributos del elemento input, pero no del label.
Cómo puedo añadirle la clase al `label` ?

```
        $builder
    ->add('nota', TextareaType::class, array(
        'label' => "Notas",
        'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('descuento', NumberType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => "oculto"
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ver en la documentación para el parámetro `label_attr` en [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#label-attr)

`'label'=>"Notes,array('label_attr' => array('class' => 'class_name'))"`